# How can I get a full control over the HTTP headers in ASP.Net WebAPI 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

The default behavior of using **HttpResponseMessage** as a return type for the Get action looks like the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-16
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 08:53:35 GMT

<my data>
```

What I want is to have a **full** control over which http header to be in the response.

Comment: You can remove some with [httpProtocol:customHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690556%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in Web.Config... Is there particular reason you want to control all headers (as there could be better solution than writing them yourself)...

Comment: I want to provide an HTTP service (NOT REST) for thin clients (micro-controller based devices).

Answer (score 2):

Default Get method in an ApiController class:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Ping()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("X-Custom-Header", "This is my custom header.");
        response.Headers.Remove("Server");

        return response;
    }
```